# Searching through List Gives wrong result

Tags: java

I have a List of type Store, where the user can add items to the list, which have a name and an id associated with them.

```
public class StoreSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList <Store> stores = new ArrayList();    

        String input = "";
        String name;
        int id = 0;
        int newId = 0;
        int index = 0;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(!(input.equals("quit"))) {
            System.out.println("Hello!\nEnter add or search");
            input = in.readLine();
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name ");
                name = in.readLine();

                System.out.println("Enter a id");
                input = in.readLine();
                id = Integer.parseInt(input);

                Store s  = new Store(name,id); 

                    if(!stores.contains(s)) 
                         stores.add(s);//only add if combination of name and id are not in it
               }

            if(input.equals("search")) {

                System.out.println("Enter a name");
                name = in.readLine();

                System.out.println("Enter a id guideline");
                input = in.readLine();
                index = input.indexOf("-");

                if(index == 0) {
                    String substring = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
                    newId = Integer.parseInt(substring);
                    Store s  = new Store(name,id); 

                    for(int counter = 0; counter < stores.size(); counter++) {
                        if(stores.contains(s)) {
                            System.out.println(stores.toString());
                        }
                    }

                }

                if(index == 4) {
                    String[] parts = input.split("\\-"); // String array, each element is text between dots
                    newId = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    //the hyphen after the 4 digit number
                }
                else {
                    //only id

                }


            }
        }

        }
    }
```

And a Store Class:

```
public class Store {
    private String name;
    private int id;

public Store(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
    public String toString() {  
        return " Name " + name + " id " + id;
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if(obj instanceof Store){
            Store element = (Store) obj;
            if(this.name.equals(element.name) && element.id == (this.id)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 61 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 61 * hash + this.id;
        return hash;
    }
}
```

I have no problems with adding to the list, where I'm only adding to the list if the combination of the thing entered, it's name and id don't exist already. however, I'm trying to search the list, which is causing me problems.

For instance, if I have added these elements to the list:

```
Snack 3366
Apple 3367
Apple 3368
```

And I wanted to search the list like this:

name being "Apple" 
Id guideline being this `"-3368"` meaning, that any object with the same name, and has an id 3368 and before, should be printed out. However, my outputted is never correct doing this. I tried using `stores.get(index);`to print out, but that still gives me the wrong output.

For the second if statement, it's checking if their is a hyphen after the 4 digit number, in this case something like "3370-" would mean all objects with the name entered, and id 3370 and above should return. Bearing in mind that I can't figure out the first if statement, I couldn't attempt the second. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `if(obj instanceof Book){`?  When are you going to want to compare a `Book` against `Store`?  Also, you could use a `Set` instead of a `List` which would guarantee unquiness

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it, also I'm forced to use an arrayList for this.

Comment: Why is `if(stores.contains(s)) {` in a for loop? You don't use `counter`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm misunderstanding the logic here, how would I go about using counter in this case?

Comment: Your example won't compile, as `id` is never assigned a value

Comment: Now you've updated it ;).  `index = input.indexOf("-");` followed by `if (index == 0) {` doesn't seem to make sense, this suggests that you're expecting the `-` to be the first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this...

```
index = input.indexOf("-");

if(index == 0) {
    String substring = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    newId = Integer.parseInt(substring);
    Store s  = new Store(name,id);
```

doesn't make sense, as it assumes that the `-` is the first character, I think you meant to use `if(index >= 0) {`

Also,

```
System.out.println("Enter a id guideline");
input = in.readLine();
input = in.readLine();
index = input.indexOf("-");
```

The double read also seems to be very odd

After tolling a bit, I think you want something more like...

```
System.out.println("Enter a name");
name = in.readLine();

System.out.println("Enter a id guideline");
input = in.readLine();
index = input.indexOf("-");

try {
    String currentIDValue = input;
    String replaceIDValue = null;
    id = 0;
    if (index >= 0) {
        currentIDValue = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf("-"));
        replaceIDValue = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);

        id = Integer.parseInt(currentIDValue);
    } else {
        id = Integer.parseInt(currentIDValue);
    }

    Store s = new Store(name, id);
    if (stores.contains(s)) {

        index = stores.indexOf(s);
        s = stores.get(index);

        System.out.println("You have selected " + s);
        if (replaceIDValue != null) {

            newId = Integer.parseInt(replaceIDValue);
            // update the ID

        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Item does not exist");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, this reads the input from the user, it checks for a `-` and takes appropriate action, now I've included the ability to perform just a search as well as a search and update

> It seems regardless of what name I put in when I have at least two objects in the list added already, when I search, I always get both objects outputted twice (2 lines). If I have Orange 2222 in the list and Orange 2223 in the list, and search for the name Orange with "-2222" I get the first result on two different lines, and the second element is also displayed, even though I'm asking for the number 2222 and below.

That's because your original code is doing exactly what you told it to do...

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < stores.size(); counter++) {
    if(stores.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println(stores.toString());
    }
}
```

for every item in the `List`, print it out, but only if the `List` contains `s`, so assuming that `s` matches any one of the items in your list, it will print ALL the items.

The loops is not required, you could simply use a combination of `List#contains` and `List#indexOf`

> "-2222" is 2222 is the new id, and the hyphen is all the previous id's with the same name. "2222-" 2222 is again the new id, hypen is the greater id's (greater than 2222 with the same name").

Okay, so we're no just searching for a single item, but a series of items which meet a specified criteria, so something like...

```
    if (input.equals("search")) {

        System.out.println("Enter a name");
        name = in.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a id guideline");
        input = in.readLine();

        String parts[] = input.split("-");

        int lower = 0;
        int upper = 0;

        if (parts.length >= 1 && parts.length <= 2) {
            if (parts.length == 2) {
                if (parts[0] != null && parts[0].trim().length() > 0) {
                    // x-x
                    lower = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    upper = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                } else {
                    // -x
                    lower = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    upper = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                }
            } else if (parts.length == 1) {
                // x-
                lower = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                upper = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            for (Store store : stores) {
                if (store.id >= lower && store.id <= upper && store.name.equals(name)) {
                    System.out.println(store);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }

    }
}
```

might be more appropriate

Comment: The double read has been fixed, but even seemingly changing the first if, still gives me the same problem. It seems regardless of what name I put in when I have at least two objects in the list added already, when I search, I always get both objects outputted twice (2 lines). If I have **Orange 2222** in the list and **Orange 2223** in the list, and search for the name Orange with "-2222" I get the first result on two different lines, and the second element is also displayed, even though I'm asking for the number 2222 and below.

Comment: First, I'd ditch the loop, `List#indexOf` is all you really need to find the location of the item you are searching for (or `-1` if it doesn't exist).  There is no exit to your loop (other the reading all the items in the `List`), so it prints ALL the items.  I've updated a portion of the based on what I "think" you're trying to do, have a look at see if that makes some more sense to you ;)

Comment: Hmm Just tried the code, got a number format exception. I'll accept your answer in a bit, I just want to get this working.

Comment: What input did you use?  I didn't account for `-2222` (as an example), I simply went for `[currentID]{-[newID]}` where the `newID` is optional, so you could do a pure search with just `2222` and a  search/update using `2222-2224`, for example

Comment: I did "-2222" thing is for my project, I have to use such input, it's required :s. I have to account for "-2222", "2222-" and "2222-2224"

Comment: Which one's which?  Which is the new id and which is the original id? Or is it a range?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, "-2222" is 2222 is the new id, and the hyphen is all the previous id's with the same name. "2222-" 2222 is again the new id, hypen is the greater id's (greater than 2222 with the same name").

Comment: And yes "2222-2224" is a range between the two (inclusive)

Comment: Ah, okay, just thought it was "find me [this] and replace with [-this]" ;)

Comment: So how would I go about incorporating "-2222" in this code? And ahh yes, it's simply the range.

Comment: Okay, so I've added a "range" searching example, might need some tweaking as I don't have all the requirements, but it should demonstrate the basic idea

Comment: Hmm, seems to work fine except for the fact that it's trying to access private variables. Thanks anyway :)